# load xml file name from user path in python

Tags: python, xml

I started working with python to modify some xml files.
I did succeed to parse and modify in my xml file using the code below:

```
from lxml import etree, objectify
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('file_name.xml', parser)  
root = tree.getroot()
```

Now I want to be able to import the file name from a path given by the user without having to change the 'file_name.xml' in my code every time manually. I did try something like this:

```
     path = input("Enter the path of file: ")
     #path = 'C:/Users/...'

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        tree = etree.parse(fullname)
        root = tree.getroot()
        print (filename , "parsed with success")
```

The problem here it doesn't work when I enter path as input, but when I specify it like in commented line it works.
PS: I am working with python 2.7 . I know it is a bit old but I don't want to change now.

Please advice,
THANK YOU!

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "it does not work"

Comment: Now I realized the error was a SyntaxError and only work if I enter the path between " "  .something with the type being string as input . How I can fix so I can enter the path without needing to insert the symbol ellipsis like this:  "C:/Users/..."